# Spring Boot ,running static blocks

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Spring framework.In my application i am trying to call a static class method,but it is running into some exception.
        The class whose method i am invoking is as :-

```
    public class BmiRangeUtility {
        private static Map<Character, BmiRangeResponse> bmiMap = null;
        static {
            List<BmiRangeResponse> bmiRange =new DefaultBmiService().findBmiRange();
            bmiRange.stream().peek(e->bmiMap.put(e.getGender(), e));
        }
        public static BmiRangeResponse getBmiMapDetails(Character gender) {
            return bmiMap.get(gender);
        }
    }
```

My DefaultBmiService is as follows :-

```
     @Service
        public class DefaultBmiService implements BmiService {
        @Autowired 
        private SomeRepository repo;
        //some methods
        }
```

Now when i run BmiRangeUtility.getBmiMapDetails('M') it is running into NullPointerException.

Comment: `private static Map<Character, BmiRangeResponse> bmiMap = null` you are declaring your map as null. and then calling put on it. obviously it will throw NPE isn't i?  Initialize your map

Answer (score 0):

Change your bmiMap to be thike this:

```
private static Map<Character, BmiRangeResponse> bmiMap = new HashMap<Character, BmiRangeResponse>();
```